# How to validate if user inserts http:// anywhere in form, display a error message?

Tags: php, forms, validation

In my form user can add all URLs of their social sites. But they cannot add a URL with `http://` or `https://`.

If user adds `http://` or `https://` in form submit; form had not submitted and its redirect my error page.

But I want If user add `http://` or `https://` in form submit, it will be display a error message and not redirect on error page.

Here is my form process. (Mysql is deprecated but I will transfer all later)

```
if(isset($_POST['update_ac'])){
$web = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['web']);
$fb = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fb']);
$tw = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tw']);
$gg = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gg']);
$fk = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fk']);
$rn = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['rn']);
$yt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['yt']);
$ig = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ig']);
$it = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['it']);
$ms = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ms']);
$pt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pt']);
$sc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sc']);
$tm = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tm']);
$vv = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['vv']);
$ws = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ws']);

# array of keys to check...
$keys =     array('web','fb','tw','gg','fk','rn','yt','ig','it','ms','pt','sc','tm','vv','ws');
# array of invalid strings to to check for...
$invalid_strings = array("http://","https://");

# array to hold errors found...
$errors = array();
foreach($keys as $key) {    # iterate through each key to check
  foreach($invalid_strings as $invalid) {   # iterate through each invalid  string
    if (strpos($_POST[$key],$invlid) > -1) {
      $errors[] = "$key cannot contain '$invalid'";
    }
  }
}
# if errors were found...
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    $error_msg = implode($errors,", ");
    echo $error_msg;
} else {
// update data in mysql database 
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE social SET web='$web', fb='$fb', tw='$tw', gg='$gg', fk='$fk', rn='$rn', yt='$yt', ig='$ig', it='$it', ms='$ms', pt='$pt', sc='$sc', tm='$tm', vv='$vv', ws='$ws' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$result=mysql_query($sql);
// if successfully updated. 
if($result){
        echo '<strong>Updated Successful</strong>';
        echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh //CONTENT="0">';
    }
    else {
        echo '<strong>Sorry !</strong> Not update, try again later';
    }
  }
}

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="<? echo $session->username; ?> (Cannot change)" disabled/>
<input name="web" type="text" id="web" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $web; ?>" size="15">
<input name="fb" type="text" id="fb" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $fb; ?>" size="15">
<input name="tw" type="text" id="tw" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $tw; ?>" size="15">
<input name="gg" type="text" id="gg" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $gg; ?>" size="15">
<input name="fk" type="text" id="fk" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $fk; ?>" size="15">
<input name="rn" type="text" id="rn" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $rn; ?>" size="15">
<input name="yt" type="text" id="yt" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $yt; ?>" size="15">
<input name="ig" type="text" id="ig" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $ig; ?>" size="15">
<input name="it" type="text" id="it" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $it; ?>" size="15">
<input name="ms" type="text" id="ms" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $ms; ?>" size="15">
<input name="pt" type="text" id="pt" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $pt; ?>" size="15">
<input name="sc" type="text" id="sc" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $sc; ?>" size="15">
<input name="tm" type="text" id="tm" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $tm; ?>" size="15">
<input name="vv" type="text" id="vv" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $vv; ?>" size="15">
<input name="ws" type="text" id="ws" placeholder="Enter url without http:// or https://" value="<? echo $ws; ?>" size="15">
<input name="userid" type="hidden" id="userid" value="<? echo $session->userid; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="update_ac" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I'd handle it...

```
<?php

# array of keys to check...
$keys = array('web','fb','tw','gg','fk','rn','yt','ig','it','ms','pt','sc','tm','vv','ws');
# array of invalid strings to to check for...
$invalid_strings = array("http://","https://");

# array to hold errors found...
$errors = array();
foreach($keys as $key) {    # iterate through each key to check
  foreach($invalid_strings as $invalid) {   # iterate through each invalid string
    if (strpos($_POST[$key],$invlid) > -1) {
      $errors[] = "$key cannot contain '$invalid'";
    }
  }
}
# if errors were found...
if (count($errors) > 0) {
    $error_msg = implode($errors,", ");
    echo $error_msg;
} else {

#  the code to run if no errors found

}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Update above with your code but not work as I want. Where is my wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

dbinns66's answer will do exactly what you want, although I would recommend to take an alternative way to your plan: instead of presenting errors if a user pastes a URL from clipboard into your form (which will happen frequently), simply remove the protocol part:

```
// remove the HTTP(S) part from a string in a case-insensitive manner
function removeProtocol($line) {
  return preg_replace('|^http?(s*)://|i', "", $line);
}

  // I tend to not overwrite superglobals, you may use $_POST[$field]= ... instead
$arrCheckedFields= array();
// fields possibly containing URLs
$arrFieldsToHandle = array('web','fb','tw','gg','fk','rn','yt','ig','it','ms','pt','sc','tm','vv','ws');
foreach($arrFieldsToHandle as $field) {  
  $arrCheckedFields[$field]= removeProtocol($_POST[$field]);
}
```

Comment: Why use preg_replace, string functions are less expensive : `$str= str_replace(array('http://', 'https://'), '', $str);`

Comment: @DarkBee in case of 20 fields to be checked, you may use `str_replace()` (or in that case [`str_ireplace`](http://php.net/str_ireplace)) or regular expressions to perform the check, it really doesn't matter. String functions are not necessarily faster, especially if you can use one regular expression instead of several string replacement functions.

Comment: @SaschaM78 - True but the OP included "it will be display a error massage and not redirect on error page." ;-) and personally I like BOTH our answers

Comment: @dbinns66 your answer IS EXACTLY what the user wanted, no discussion about that! :-) On the other hand I personally care a lot about good UX, that's why I recommended an alternative way to proposed functionality.